# Micro services with Minio implementation

Tags: minio, file-type

I have a micro service project which need to use minio as the object storage. I have 2
spring boot projects (micro services) which are called admin-service and document-service. In document service i need to write the logic to upload the file into Minio. From admin-service project I want be able to call the document-service by parsing the file I need to upload in to the Minio.

I need to know how should I implement file sharing mechanism in this scenario? How I should share file among 2 services? Is it as Multipart file or any other type?

Note: I am going to use web client for service calling